# Remove duplicate values in a bidimensional array starting from index 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

Which is the best way to remove duplicate values from bidimensional array? For example, my array looks like this:

```
var bid_array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,6,7,8,2],[7,2,4,9,11,15],[10,12,3,7,11]];
```

I need to start evaluating the `bid_array[0]` and check if `bid_array[1]`, `bid_array[2]` or `bid_array[3]` contains a value that already exist in the `bid_array[0]`, if exist delete the value duplicated from conflict array and when we have finished to check the last array now start from the second index position (`bid_array[1]`) and go ahead again to check the next sub-arrays.

I was trying this, but only works if there are just 1 value duplicated max two times. Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bid_array.length; j++) {
    for (var k = (j + i); k < bid_array.length; k++) {
      for (var l = 0; l < bid_array[k].length; l++) {
        if (bid_array[j].indexOf(bid_array[k][l]) > -1) {
          bid_array[k].splice(l, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want that the original array that before was:

```
var bid_array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,6,7,8,2],[7,2,4,9,11,15],[10,12,3,7,11]];
```

Be, after remove all duplicate values and just keeping one:

```
var bid_array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,11,15],[10,12]];
```

What's the best way to do this having the security that all duplicated values was removed just keeping one? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in the following way

```js
var bid_array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,6,7,8,2],[7,2,4,9,11,15],[10,12,3,7,11]];

let map = {};
bid_array = bid_array.map(function(element){
    return element.filter(function(val){
        if(map[val])
          return 0;
        map[val] = 1;
        return 1;
    });
})

console.log(bid_array);
```

Comment: This code works a lot and thank you, but, what exactly `map` do? I'm not sure to undestand what does do piece of code after `bid_array.map(function(element) { ...)`.

Comment: It iterates element by element and returns the altered value in that place

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and a check.

```js
function unique(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    return array.map(function (a) {
        return a.filter(function (b) {
            return !hash[b] && (hash[b] = true);
        });
    });
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2], [7, 2, 4, 9, 11, 15], [10, 12, 3, 7, 11]];

console.log(unique(array));
```

ES5 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function unique(array) {
    var hash = new Set;
    return array.map(a => a.filter(b => !hash.has(b) && hash.add(b)));
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2], [7, 2, 4, 9, 11, 15], [10, 12, 3, 7, 11]];

console.log(unique(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

A perfect Set usecase:

```
var set = new Set();
for(const array of bid_array){
 var c = 0;
 array.slice().forEach((el,i) => {
   if(set.has(el)){
      array.splice(i-(c++),1);
   }else{
       set.add(el);
   }
  }); 
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to run into the problem of mutating an array while performing a forward iteration. When you come across two adjacent numbers that need to be removed, the second one will be skipped over.

Comment: Yep, `forEach` doesn't have any way to know what has been mutated. It actually caches the `.length` of the collection and goes to that end, but you don't notice it because it performs a `HasProperty` check on each index, so when it goes out of bounds, the callback isn't invoked. It's pretty much just a simple loop.